# What kind of place would a place be when attached to the word "auto"?

Tags: word-meaning

**[In this video,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OhB-RmoWjg)**

From:0:23

> "ABC's Markas Morzan, **auto**-Texas, where 2 tornadoes touched down."

Could someone teach me what "auto" means here?

Comment: Or did I mishear his words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misheard. It is the name of the place, *[Alto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alto,_Texas)*, in Texas.

Alto is the name of the town, Texas is the US state in which the town resides.